# Missing one label on Histogram and adjustments make other labels not visible

Tags: label, histogram

I have created a histogram and have added labels.  When I get the result there is one label that is off the top because of it's value.  I tried using the vjust adjustment, and it didn't work because other labels were then on the x axis and difficult to see.  How can I show the missing label without moving the rest of the labels?

Data<-new<-c(Recipient, Country, SP.Age), SP.Age(0-39)

p<-ggplot(new,aes(x=SP.Age))
+geom_histogram(fill="#99CCFF", color="#00FF66",bins=40)+scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))+
stat_bin(binwidth=1, geom='text',size=2,color='dark blue', aes(label=..count..),hjust=0.5,vjust=-0.5)

[image: Histogram]